# Laravel ->Send a complete table out of the controller

Tags: ajax, laravel, controller

I would like to echo a table of scores within a Ajax function. Everything works (connection Ajax/Controller), but how can I create a table in my controller, that sends a whole table?

```
$scores = DB::table('scores')->select('teamname', 'score')->get();
```

Wishful outcome (It should be variables, depending on outcome of query):

```
response()->json(['success'=>'<table><tr><th>Teamname</th><th>Score</th></tr><tr><td>Teamname1</td><td>12</td></tr><tr><td>Teamname2</td><td>10</td></tr></table>']);
```

Should I make an array of $scores? Or do I need to loop to return the values? I hope you guys can help me!

Comment: You have to use loop $scores.

Comment: You should return a view, not a json, this is messy

Comment: @GertB. can I return a view with Ajax? The page who ask for the score should not refresh.

Comment: @NiekNeuvel you can return a view for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should render the view and then you can send it in the AJAX.

Please add the below line in the controller file:

```
$table_view = return view('score_table.blade.php', $scores)->render();    
return response()->json(['status' => true, 'table_view' => $table_view]);
```

After that create one file `score_table.blade.php` in your resources folder. In that file your code should be like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th> Teamname </th>
        <th> Score </th>
    </tr>
    @foreach($scores as $score)
        <tr>
            <td> {{ $score->name }} </td>
            <td> {{ $score->score_number }} </td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
</table>
```

Comment: I think I have to change my Ajax Post too? I've added your answers, but it's shows no data at the place I want. 

$.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:"/ajaxRequest",
        data:{_token: _token},
        success:function(data){
            
            $('#scoreresult').html(data);

         }
    });

Comment: Are you sure you got your result in the `$table_view`? And if yes then make sure that you got the JSON data, not the simple data you have to use [this](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/). and then replace `html(data)` to `html(data.table_view)`

Comment: $table_view = view('score_table.blade.php', $scores)->render();

Visual studio code don't accept the return function in a variable.

Answer (score 2):

To create html table in the controller, **is not a good practice** (and it is an anti-pattern too). Framework like Laravel was born precisely to separate almost three layers: the "logic", the "data" and the "views".

Html table belongs to "views" layer.

You can do that in two ways:

### First way

If you call an Ajax from client, in response you can serve a json of the DATA (not HTML) of your table. And then parse this json data in your html structure in `blade` or any other html page.

So, in your case, in Controller:

```
$scores = DB::table('scores')->select('teamname', 'score')->get();

return response()->json(['scores' => $scores]);
```

In your javascript get response and parse data. For example, with Axios:

```
axios.get('url-of-ajax-call')
     .then((success) => function(){
         let scores = success.data.scores
     })
     .catch(error => console.error(error))
```

then you can use the `scores` js variable in your html.

### Second way

You can use directly blade template, without any ajax call.

In this case:

- In Controller:

```
$scores = DB::table('scores')->select('teamname', 'score')->get();
return view('your-blade-page-under-resources-folder', ['scores' => $scores])
```

- in `your-page.blade.php`, something like this:

```
 <table>
  <tr>
    <th>Teamname</th>
    <th>Score</th>
  </tr>

  @foreach($scores as $score)
    <tr>
      <td>{{ $score->name }}</td>
      <td>{{ $score->score }}</td>
    </tr>
  @endforeach

</table>
```